# Select data is very slowly when I have more data

Tags: angular, performance, typescript, select

Select view is slow, but when I have more data select is very very slow.

I used this code:

HTML

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="input-field col s8">
      <div formArrayName="data_id">
        <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let itemm of editdataForm.get('data_id').value; let i = index">
          <br>
          <select formControlName="{{i}}" id="data_id" materialize="material_select" [materializeSelectOptions]="items"
            [ngClass]="{invalid: invalidInputs}">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Data</option>
            <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.data_id">{{item.data_name}}</option>
          </select>
          <div class="button-left">
            <button *ngIf="editdataForm.controls.data_id.value.length > 1" type="button" class="fa" (click)="onRemoveItem(i)">x</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s2">
      <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="onAddData()">AddData</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

TS

```
   this.editdataForm= new FormGroup({
      'data_id': this.fb.array([]),
      .........
    });
  populateFormData() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        this.hps.getdata(params['id']).subscribe(
          data=> {
            this.data= data;
            ....
            this.data.sensors.forEach(x => {
              (this.editdataForm.get('data_id') as FormArray).push(new FormControl(x.data_id))
            });
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
  onAddData() {
    (<FormArray>this.editdataForm.controls['data_id']).push(new FormControl('', Validators.required));
  }
  onRemoveItem(index: number) {
    (<FormArray>this.editdataForm.controls['data_id']).removeAt(index);
  }
```

This code works good but very slow when there are many data. Please, can you ask me any idea how to optimization this ? How to make to work fast?

Thank you!

Comment: More data - How many items?

Comment: Yes, more than 4000 data

Comment: Very few websites would build a select with so many items. Try just a plain HTML page with that many items. It would also be slow. You may want to consider how you could redesign so you have fewer. As a user, I would not want to scroll through thousands of items. (just my opinion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change how you get the data from backend

```
populateFormData() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
       flatMap(params => this.hps.getdata(params['id']))
    ).subscribe(
          data=> {
            this.data= data;
            ....
            this.data.sensors.forEach(x => {
              (this.editdataForm.get('data_id')as FormArray).push(new FormControl(x.data_id))
            });
          }
        );
  }
```

also you can create a small method that return your FormArray easily

```
get data_id ():FormArray {
  return this.editdataForm.get('data_id')
}
```

and then your code from populateFormData will change a bit

from  `(this.editdataForm.get('data_id')as FormArray).push(new FormControl(x.data_id))`

will be `this.data_id.push(new FormControl(x.data_id))`

you can also use the method previously created in the html template

**UPDATE**

the main improve you can do is change the way that you handle the subscriptions to get the data. the code that I share is how you can do it , an example, 
the other method is just to make your code more simple, you can use you own code to setup the data in your form array

Comment: In wich part of code I write this: `get data_id ():FormArray =>this.editdataForm.get('data_id')`

Comment: that is a new method created, you need to add it to your code

Comment: Please, I don't understand, can you write it in my code post please?

Comment: `Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.`

Comment: Now show this error: `Type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to type 'FormArray'.
  Property 'controls' is missing in type 'AbstractControl'.`

Comment: In html I write  `<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let itemm of data_id.controls; let i = index">` and looks good. thnx